# problemas con is_null()

Tags: php, laravel

Con is_null() pretendo dirigir el programa a dos situaciones diferentes.
Obtengo una línea con el siguiente código :

```
$linea=$this->getModel()->where('tipoiva','=',$tipoiva)->
                                           where('factura_id','=',$facturarecibida_id)->
                                           where('suscriptor_id','=',$suscriptor_id)->get()
```

Esta línea existirá si se cumplen las condiciones where anteriores.
Para saberlo programo lo siguiente:

```
if ( is_null($linea) ){
    Log::Info("Existe  el acumulado del  tipo");
 }else{
        Log::Info("No existe  el acumulado del  tipo ");
    }
```

> El resultado siempre es el mismo: No existe el acumulado del tipo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado utilizar `isset()`?

Comment: Si te regresa una colección bien podrías utilizar empty en lugar de is_null, no hay problema ya que Collection implementa Countable y se enlaza directamente a la cantidad de items de la colección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que estás usando *Laravel* y *Eloquent*, por lo que:

```
$linea=$this->getModel()
    ->where('tipoiva','=',$tipoiva)
    ->where('factura_id','=',$facturarecibida_id)
    ->where('suscriptor_id','=',$suscriptor_id)
    ->get();
```

De ese fragmento de código vas a obtener todos los registros que cumplan las condiciones especificadas o un objeto tipo *stdClass* vacío si no hay coincidencias. [Referencia método get()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results).

No estoy seguro si en algún momento el método puede devolver un valor nulo, tal vez si hay error en la consulta, pero, en todo caso, se lanzaría una excepción. Suponiendo que devuelve nulo en caso de no encontrar registros, tu lógica parece estar al revés:

```
if(is_null($linea)) {
    // No se encontraron registros
    Log::Info("No existe  el acumulado del  tipo");
} else {
    // Sí hay registros que cumplen con la condición
    Log::Info("Existe  el acumulado del  tipo");
}
```

Lo más adecuado sería contar la cantidad de registros devueltos usando `count()` en lugar de `is_null()`:

```
if(count($linea) == 0) {
    // Cero resultados quiere decir que no existe el acumulado
    Log::Info("No existe  el acumulado del  tipo");
} else {
    // Uno o más registros, quiere decir que sí existe el acumulado
    Log::Info("Existe  el acumulado del  tipo");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hacer esto:

```
is_null($linea);
```

Te tendría que estar devolviendo `false`, ya que [`is_null`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-null.php) evalúa si una variable es nula lo cual mas adelante comprobaremos que no es así.

Usar el método `get()` al final de tu consulta retorna una colección de objetos.

Con eso en mente asumamos que si la consulta no consigue registro alguno, nos daría una salida como esta:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4078
     all: [],
   }
```

Lo cual evidentemente no es `null`

Ahora bien construyamos una consulta de ejemplo:

```
    $consulta = Modelo::whereIn('id', [10, 20])->get();
```

Entonces la forma en que puedes evaluar si la colección tiene o no objetos es con ayuda del método `isEmpty()` de la clase `Collection` el cual en el propio framework indica: ***Determine if the collection is empty or not.*** al retornar `true` si esta vacía y `false` si no lo esta.

Mediante un condicional apoyándonos de dicho método lo resolvemos así:

```
if ($consulta->isEmpty()) {
    // acciones si la colección no tiene objetos
} else {
    // acciones si la colección si tiene objetos
}
```

Comment: @ BetaM   Gracias por la aclaración muy interesante  , una última pregunta ¿ como puedo obtener la ID de la línea "No_null"  $linea->id no funciona

Comment: Ya marqué la respuesta que resolvió la duda

Comment: Ya marqué la respuesta que resolvió la duda

Answer (score 1):

Porque no utilizas validando si es true de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($llamado == true) {
  echo "verdadero";
} else {
  echo "falso";
}
```

Comment: ,Entiendo que $llamado correspondería a $linea y si es verdadero será porque es null , no contiene ningún tipo de objeto

Comment: el resultado de la consulta es una colección de objetos y no un valor booleano, por tanto no sirve compararla contra `true`