# Por que no funciona la condición empty en mi sistema laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

no se por qué me da como resultado esto: NO VIENE VACIO [] en la pantalla, y si hago un dd($productos) aparece esto: Collection {#446 ▼
#items: []
} aquí hay una pequeña prueba de lo que estoy haciendo, no es el código original pero debería de funcionar distinto.

```
@if (empty($productos))
          VIENE VACIO
          {{$productos}}
        @else
          NO VIENE VACIO
          {{$productos}}
        @endif
```

estoy trabajando con laravel version 5.8
he refrescado todo por cuestiones de que no guarde basura la aplicación. (php artisan cache:clear, php artisan config:cache, php artisan route:clear y php artisan view:clear)

como podría resultarme la condición?

Comment: Has dd de productos y agrega a tu pregunta que sale

Comment: ya lo agregué el codigo

Comment: Cambia ese método por isEmpty y dime si te funcionó, revisa aquí https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-isempty

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [problemas con is\_null()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388042/problemas-con-is-null)

Comment: fijate que no sé como aplicarlo a pesar de ver el ejemplo, intenté ponerlo en el controlador y en la vista y nada.

Comment: is_null me aparece lo mismo que empty, osea "NO VIENE VACIO [] " cuando en realidad me lo está mostrando como vacío.

Comment: No no igual no me explique prueba isEmpty como lo puse en mi respuesta

Comment: MauEspaña lo que @BetaM te sugiere es que uses isEmpty porque in_null no va a funcionar pues la salida de get aún en caso de no haber coincidencias no va a ser null. **Mira la respuesta aclaratoria agregada por BetaM** no la aceptada.

Comment: ¿Dentro de `$productos` hay una propiedad `items`? De ser así, deberías evaluar `$productos->items` porque, a pesar de que sea un arreglo vacío, hace que `$productos` tenga contenido y "falle" la evaluación.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar `->isEmpty()` cuando trabajas con Collection.

```
if($productos->isEmpty())
```

O puedes intentar esta otra manera:

```
if($productos->count())
```

Esa última devuelve la cantidad de elementos de la colección, si no tiene, devolverá 0 y no pasará la condición, caso contrario, devolverá N, algún número mayor que cero y será verdadero